# Linked list insertion

Tags: c++, linked-list

The EmissonList object is a List of Shows with certain info. The problem I look for is in the insert function.

```
class EmissionList {
private:
Emission *head=NULL;
public:
void insert(Emission *aNode);
Emission *getHead() {
    return head;
};
void putHead(Emission *newHead) {
    head=newHead;
    head->next = NULL;
}
void printEmissions();
};


void EmissionList::insert(Emission *aNode) {
Emission *ptr=getHead();
if (head == NULL){
    putHead(aNode);
}else{
    while(ptr!= NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr = aNode;
    ptr->next=NULL;
}}
```

I am trying to add to the list but I encounter problems.

Comment: Why not use one of the templates? Job done

Comment: tried answear 1 and still having problems. I have to can't use std::list and templates. The code has to be like this and i have to implement a insert function,

Comment: " but I encounter problems.", your question,should explain what problems, exactly. Like compiler error, which and where? Crash? Wrong output, what?

Comment: The question has be answeared.

Answer (score 0):

In your code when you set ptr = aNode ptr is not the 'next' of last element and so original list is unchanged

I suggest you std::list or, at least

```
for (Emission **iter = &head ; *iter != NULL ; )
    iter = &((*iter)->next) ;
*iter = aNode ;
```

It's the simplest insertion (at end) I have found so far.

Comment: getting errors for your code. Can you give it inside my insert

Answer (score 0):

First of all the design of the class EmissionList is bad.

Nevertheless the function can be defined the following way

```
void EmissionList::insert( Emission *aNode ) 
{
    Emission *current = getHead();

    if ( current == NULL )
    {
        putHead( aNode );
    }
    else
    {
       while ( current->next ) current = current->next;
       aNode->next = current->next;
       current->next = aNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dimitris Karagiannis And In Italian grazie.:)